# Cross validation with specific test size

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was earlier using cross_validation.train_test_split to split my dataset into a 90:10 ratio. I now moved to Stratified Shuffle Split( a merge of Kfold and Shuffle Split in scikit-learn). I want to understand if whether doing stratified division with a specified test size is better or should I just do it without speicfying a test size?

This is what I am doing:

```
train=[]
with open("/Users/minks/Documents/documents.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        train.append(line.strip().split())
train=np.array(train)
labels=[]
with open("/Users/minks/Documents/Labels.txt") as t:
    for line in t:
        labels.extend(line.strip().split())
labels=np.array(labels)

kf=StratifiedShuffleSplit(labels, n_iter=5, test_size=0.10)

for train_index, test_index in kf:
     X_train, X_test = train[train_index],train[test_index]
     Y_train, Y_test = labels[train_index],labels[test_index]
```

I want to know if specifying a test_size is a good decision for performance or not since if I don't do so it picks up random ratios.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify your own test size, it will default to `0.1`. It will not use random ratios. You can find the default value in the docs(tring of the function):

in an IPython, do

```
[1]: from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
[2]: StratifiedShuffleSplit?
```

You will see

```
[...]
Parameters
----------
n : int
    Total number of elements in the dataset.

n_iter : int (default 10)
    Number of re-shuffling & splitting iterations.

test_size : float (default 0.1), int, or None
    If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the
    proportion of the dataset to include in the test split. If
    int, represents the absolute number of test samples. If None,
    the value is automatically set to the complement of the train size.

[...]
```